# Custom data structure with constant time push and popmin

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I recently got this question in an interview:

> Design a data structure that supports 2 operations:
>
> 1. push(N) - stores a number
> 2. popmin() - extract the current minimum of all stored numbers and remove it from storage
>
> Both push and popmin must execute in O(1) time.

At first I thought of using 2 stacks but that only allows getting the minimum number, not removing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible, since you would be able to use such a data structure to implement a linear time sort.

Comment: Are there additional constraints on the numbers to be stored (i.e. integers in a given range)? I don't believe the current version of the question is solvable, as a data structure with `O(1)` `push` and `pop_min` would allow an `O(n)` sorting algorithm to be constructed. It's well known that `O(n*log(n))` is the best case for a general comparison based sort...

Comment: you could use primary queue, but there's no constant time insert for one item.

Comment: I think you are all right. This is probably a trick question. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a quick proof that in the comparison model this isn’t possible. Start with n values and push each of them, then execute n popmins. This will then return the elements in sorted order in time O(n), violating the Ω(n log n) sorting barrier.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of [heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants) that allow for insert and find min in O(1). The issue is removing the min requires O(log N). It seems to imply that either information is missing or incorrect.

Comment: I think you are right. This is probably a trick question. Thanks anyways!